# Is there a shortcut (missing?) to move tab in xfce4 terminal app?

Tags: debian, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

Using xfce4 in a Debian/Linux Jessie/Sid distribution, I am unable to find or set shortcut to move tab position in xfce4 terminal, like Ctrl-Shift-DgDown/PgUp in gnome terminal.

This is really lacking. Do someone know something about ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally find my way:

- first [enable shortcut accelerators](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/appearance#menus_and_buttons);
- then you can add, change or remove shortcut by pointing the mouse pointer on action in menu you wish to modify and tape the shortcut or backspace to delete it.

Answer (score 5):

Plain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd> should work to cycle tabs.  There's a option in the "Tabs" menu which shows the shortcuts.

[image]

If you don't see the menu bar, right click inside the terminal window and pick "Show Menubar".

Comment: Thanks for this, but what iam looking for is the shortcuts for the both "move tab left" and "move tab right" who are not specified as we can see on your screenshot.