# How to make editable accelerators in xfce terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I know there was a question on how to edit shortcuts for tab in xfce terminal: [Is there a shortcut (missing?) to move tab in xfce4 terminal app?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166427/is-there-a-shortcut-missing-to-move-tab-in-xfce4-terminal-app), but I did what said (that is - enable editable accelerators in appearance settings), and still cannot change shortcuts in the menubar. My purpose is to change shortcut for 1) `open tab`, which is 
`<shift><ctrl>t` to `<ctrl>t` and 2) `close tab`, which is `<shift><ctrk>w` to `<ctrl>t` (basically getting rid of the `<ctrl>` key of them). I have tried to hover over them, pressed delete, and then typed those keys, to set the shortcuts, but nothing had happened. So is there a possibility to change defaul xfce terminal shortcuts for my purpose mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to change the shortcuts using the "editable accelerators" and according to [this post](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12105) in the XFCE forum this only works for GTK2 applications.

You can change the defaults in `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm` (just like in your previous question [How to switch  from interrupt to copy, and  to  in xfc4-terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586882/how-to-switch-ctrl-c-from-interrupt-to-copy-and-ctrl-v-to-ctrl-v-in-xfc4)).

To get rid of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you open or close a tab, change

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/close-tab" "<Primary><Shift>w")
```

and

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/new-tab" "<Primary><Shift>t")
```

to

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/close-tab" "<Primary><Shift>w")
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/close-tab" "<Primary>w")
```

and

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/new-tab" "<Primary><Shift>t")
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/new-tab" "<Primary>t")
```